# Can I tell IIS to process some requests sequentially and asynchronously?

Tags: iis, queue

Can I tell IIS to process some requests sequentially and asynchronously?

Basically, I want some sort of queue for some kind of requests that will execute requests one after the other and, when a new request gets in the queue, IIS to return OK and not wait for it to execute.

Is this possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have some problems with some requests that must be executed sequentially (otherwise they fail). So, in order to avoid making my own (async+sequential) queue in an MVC controller, I though that perhaps IIS can do that for me.

Comment: No can do. Use [MSMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) for that.

Comment: OK. I was just wondering if IIS could do that. So Thanks. :) Now I know that it can't.